# Wait for another function to complete within MessageKit function

Tags: swift, messagekit

Thanks to the people that helped me on my other SA question, I was able to create a function that returns a boolean to see if a user already voted on a chat message. I want to print if the person voted on the chat message using the MessageKit `messageBottomLabelAttributedText` function. However, I'm unable to use the returned boolean value to print the correct text.

Here's my current messageBottomLabelAttributedText function within MessagesDataSource:

```
    func messageBottomLabelAttributedText(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {

        var bool = didAlreadyVote(message: message as! MessageType){_ in Bool.self}

        if bool as? Bool == true {
            let dateString = self.formatter.string(from: message.sentDate)
            let likeString = "Voted"
            return NSAttributedString(string: "\(dateString) | \(likeString)", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption2)])
        } else {
            let dateString = self.formatter.string(from: message.sentDate)
            return NSAttributedString(string: dateString, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption2)])
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, here's the didAlreadyVote function this community helped me out with earlier:

```
func didAlreadyVote(message: MessageType, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    // check user votes collection to see if current message matches
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {return}
    let userID = currentUser.uid
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userID).collection("upvotes").whereField("messageId", isEqualTo: message.messageId)

    docRef.getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in

        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            completion(false)
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                completion(true) /// Note that this will get called multiple times if you have more the one document!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app, the bool variable doesn't return anything. How can I retrieve the boolean from the function and then use it within messageBottomLabelAttributedText?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Don't wait.**

`didAlreadyVote` doesn't **return** anything. It contains an asynchronous completion handler which passes the `Bool` value as parameter.

The syntax is

```
    didAlreadyVote(message: message){ boolValue in   
        if boolValue {
            let dateString = self.formatter.string(from: message.sentDate)
            let likeString = "Voted"
            return NSAttributedString(string: "\(dateString) | \(likeString)", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption2)])
        } else {
            let dateString = self.formatter.string(from: message.sentDate)
            return NSAttributedString(string: dateString, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption2)])
        }
```

but you can't use it in `messageBottomLabelAttributedText` anyway because you can't return anything unless you implement also a completion handler for example

```
func messageBottomLabelAttributedText(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, completion: @escaping (NSAttributedString) -> Void) {
    didAlreadyVote(message: message){ boolValue in   
        if boolValue {
            let dateString = self.formatter.string(from: message.sentDate)
            let likeString = "Voted"
            completion(NSAttributedString(string: "\(dateString) | \(likeString)", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption2)]))
        } else {
            let dateString = self.formatter.string(from: message.sentDate)
            completion(NSAttributedString(string: dateString, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption2)]))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation! Trying to absorb this all. So I replaced my `messageBottomLabelAttributedText` function with yours above but now the function isn't being hit at all when I run the app. Does MessageKit ignore it now that the completion handler was added?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MessageKit. If `messageBottomLabelAttributedText` is part of the framework you can't change it and you have to find another way to to handle the asynchronous data.

Comment: bummer, that's what I was afraid of. Thank you anyways!